# android-tab new contents while viewing it?

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

Some apps have this feature, that when a new post is added while the app is in the foreground it shows this view:

[image: foreground view]

Can anybody offer **an article or blog post** to get this view with animation and all that?

I can do it by myself, but I want it to look professional.

Any advice would be appreciated.